# What open source license allows everything except modification?

Tags: license-recommendation, license

There are so many licenses that honestly they are making me dizzy. Here is what I want to do:

1. require my copyright notice and no-warranty statement.
2. permit people to use + run my code.
3. don't permit people to modify my code because I don't want to see hybrids of mine+others' files out there.
4. permit people to incorporate my code as a library in their projects.
5. permit people to copy, sell, distribute my code.

The modification issue stems from my not wanting to fuss over what part of a modified file was my code and what is the other person's. I would prefer if people email me to point out bugs or make suggestions.

Is there such a license out there?

Comment: This would not be an open source license - the [freedom to modify is one of the core definitions of open source](https://opensource.org/docs/osd).

Comment: @PhilipKendall that's the answer.  As per [this question](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-do-we-feel-about-answers-presented-as-comments), please consider (fleshing it out a little and) posting it as one, so it can be upvoted and (hopefully) accepted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it explicitly asks for a license prohibiting modifications.

Comment: @curiousdannii This is just a typical misunderstanding, caused by a name that seems to but does not describe what it is. Unfortunately to understand Open Source you need to memorise the definition. Or you can understand [Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), and realise that they are the same software, but different philosophy.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out another reason not to want other people to modify your software. While I would like other people to benefit from the project I have in mind, it's a hobby project in a language I don't get to use during the day, and I want the fun of doing my own development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epsilon is a software which chose to use a license as you describe. Here is a talk about that license and the different problems it can cause:

https://github.com/numworks/epsilon/issues/38

What you are looking for would be this type of license:

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode

I do not really see a problem with others playing with your code. In most cases, though the source remains the main version and the forks are only checked for possible enhancements and/or bugs that would need to be fixed in the main source. So it can really be helpful to have people help you improve your work.

For Epsilon, I suppose it is from a company and a team works on the project.

If you're by yourself, why not have a few people help every now and then?!

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Creative Commons discourages the use of their licenses for software. 2. A larger product that uses a library can be seen as a derivative work of that library. This would go against the No Derivatives clause of the CC BY-NC-ND license.

Comment: Yeah, I do not know of other licenses that offer what the OP is looking for. And as you mention, it opens all sorts of can of worms.

Comment: Not all creative commons licences are Free/Open source. e.g. the `nc` and `nd` ones.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Open Source licence.

see extract from definition https://opensource.org/osd

> 3. Derived Works The license must allow modifications and derived works, and must allow them to be distributed under the same terms as
>      the license of the original software.

However did you know that this **does not mean** that people have permission to edit your copy of the code. And a licence is not the way to stop people breaking your personal files.

Comment: Then "open source" is a misnomer.

Comment: @user15474 yes the name is confusing, I agree. It is pure abstract and has little connection to its meaning. This is one reason that I prefer to say Free Software. This way the only confusion is on which meaning of Free I am using (Free as in freedom, not Free as in a contraction of free-of-charge).

Comment: @user15474 Can you enlighten as to why you down-voted?, so that I can correct the answer.